# Updating chipset drivers on Win10x64

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, chipset

So I want to update my chipset drivers. From what I see on [this page](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81M-HDS/?cat=Download&os=Win1064), I can download an INF driver which should update my chipset. When I started the installer it told me to check if my chipset is supported. This is my chispet:

`Intel(R) 8 Series/C220 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller`

I couldn't find anything on the web, so I'm asking here if someone more experienced could tell me whether the `INF driver ver:10.1.1.8` actually supports the above shown chipset.

Comment: For the latest Intel AHCI driver (for consumer chipsets), you just need to search `rst` on the download center: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=rst Currently this is the latest one: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25165/ Get `f6flpy-x64.zip` for 64-bit Windows. FYR, http://i.stack.imgur.com/V0FpT.png

Comment: Windows 10 has AHCI drivers built-in.  Your problem isn't caused by drivers.  What problem are you actually experiencing?  Unless the author is trying to setup a RAID, I am not sure the reason, the author needs [`Intel Rapid Storage Technology`](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology.html) installed.

Comment: @TomYan How can I install these?

Comment: @PowerUser - Run the installer.

Comment: There is no installer, only 2 `.cat` files, a bunch of `.sys` and `.inf` files too. But no `.exe` nor `.msi`.

Comment: @PowerUser see the `Update Driver...` button on the screenshot I pasted? Go to `Device Manager` -> `IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers` -> `Intel(R) 8 Series/C220 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller`

Comment: and browse my computer for the files?

Comment: why do you need to update the chipset drivers in the first place ? what are you trying to achieve ? as Windows 10 has a good drivers detector, and it would install them automatically. Surly, there are some cases that you need to install some drivers manually. So we need to know what is the problem that led you to update your chipset drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck.  I have exactly the same hardware and know the link for the latest version of it:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/55005/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-

The drivers you're looking for are the *14 series*.  Click "Show More" and download 14.8.14.1063.  As of right now those are the latest.  The 15 and 14 series are mixed in on that same download page.  You will always want a 14 series driver as the 15 is for newer hardware.

Comment: The hardware you mentioned is for your hard drive and the above post is 100% correct for it.  For *general* chipset drivers though here is the link for those:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/20775/Intel-Chipset-Device-Software-INF-Update-Utility-

I keep track of all my hardware and have correct links for same.  I'm also Windows 10 x64 as you are.

Comment: And just noticed that this is an old post.  Oh well, perhaps the links will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try the drivers from Station-Drivers (French site, has the greatest collection of device drivers on the planet) at http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=select&id=406&lang=en. I'd recommend 10.1.1.14, and it should self-install from this download package.